# How would I check a user of my website is a subscriber of a youtube channel?

Tags: web, youtube, google-authentication

I am trying to create a website that checks if the current logged-in user is subscribed to a specific youtube channel. This is meant to restrict the user if they haven't yet. Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the user to login via [google identity services](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web) to be able to access data like that via the api. The [api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) gives you access to the channels the user is subscribed to if the user allows this

Comment: Yes. I was thinking that google's api would be necessary. Thanks for sharing the documentation links. Very helpful.